# Heroku Deployment error-Nltk Unable to download

Tags: python-3.x, heroku, machine-learning, nltk, web-deployment

I deployed my project on Heroku with heroku/python as Buildpack then with github link from Learn more section of image as Buildpack. It is not working
with any of the buildpacks.

[image: Error occur:Nltk.txt not found]

Please help me out

Answer (score 1):

It seems you should create a `nltk.txt` file to download the corpora that you are interested in, as mentioned in the link.

```
In order to use it, you have to download corpora
and make it available to your application.
```

This is not *required* by NLTK, so they are simply letting you know that no corpora will be downloaded.

you can go to http://www.nltk.org/nltk_data/ to see a list of corpora available or in a python terminal run:

```
>>> import nltk
>>> nltk.download()
```

Then simply choose and install what you want.

Comment: After including this in my code and I deployed it to the Heroku cloud. The application is working correctly only for the first input. But for the second, it showing me the same Output from the first input. what should I do to rectify that

Comment: I don't know what your inputs or outputs are, or what you are trying to achieve. please ask another question about your new issue.